# How can I diagnose/fix a Rock Band 3 MIDI controller that stopped working?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii, rock-band-3

We have Rock Band 3 for Wii, with the [Mad Catz Rock Band Midi-Pro Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00409SOEG), and a Yamaha P-95 keyboard. This was working *just fine*. We hadn't used the keyboard with RB3 for a while, and when we plugged it back in, no go.

The buttons on the controller itself work fine to talk to the Wii and control the game. When we switch the D/K/G switch to "G" (just trying things), it blinks the S. O. S. pattern. But when it's on K, the MIDI signal light doesn't blink. (And, of course, no actual keys received in the game.)

Crucially, *this was working*. It's not like the thing has batteries. What could have gone wrong, and what might we do about it? The [manual](http://rockbandsupport.madcatz.com/KB/a113/nintendo-wii-manuals.aspx) is no help. I also looked in the [Yamaha P-95](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical-instruments/keyboards/digitalpianos/p_series/p-95_color_variation/?mode=model) manual, and although I didn't need to do it to get the adapter working initially, I reset the keyboard to factory defaults and tried variously setting the MIDI out channel to 1 and 10.

What else can/should I do? New ones are $35, so I could just suck it up and get a new one, but I don't want to do that if it's not likely to even solve the problem (or if it could be fixed in some other way).

Comment: can you buy a new one from Amazon or some other place with a good return policy? Honestly the easiest thing to do here is to swap it out and see what happens...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And the solution: replace the MIDI cable. Problem went away; everything works fine.

Comment: That would have been my first suggestion, but I have a CCNA-based "cables first!" diagnostic ethic. :P

Comment: I was coming to suggest this.  ALWAYS check the cables first...